# Java Android send data between two devices by the internet

Tags: java, android, sockets, communication

I searched for a solution for the communication ( for example send data ... ) between two devices with an application who is available at both devices. It has to be done by the Internet without a Server in between. I read something about socket and Server socket. Is this the best way or are there any other ways? Or can someone show a short example? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: In a roundabout way you're asking : "can Android do peer 2 peer file sharing?" - I suggest you have a Google, as this is not really a programming problem, I also suggest you broaden to looking at pure Java libraries as well.

Comment: What kind of connection would there be between the devices? Mobile? Wifi? Please tell your setup.

Comment: since we are on different networks this is not going to work we need some one intermediate who can listen to all clients and serve them.

Comment: I would like to do this by mobile.

Comment: Then it is impossible.

Comment: Android supports writing TCP servers  but Mobile providers usually block devices from receiving inbound connections over Cellular, they only allow outbound connections. So you need an intermediate server running on the Internet that devices can connect to. You don't need that over WiFi.